# How to Implement Google Map Tile Provider in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am working on custom map app and i want to use google map tiles for background ? There is one class `TileProvider` in api but i don't know how to initialize it every time i try it goes something like this ?

```
TileProvider tileProvider=new TileProvider() {
    @Override
    public Tile getTile(int i, int i2, int i3) {
        return null;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
};
```

how to override getTile function to get tiles from google map server?
Any example will be appreciated ?I know `getTile` function need x,y and zoom value to return tile.

Answer (score 1):

So quick answer is that you can get the Google Map tiles from the following URL:

```
http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs={t}&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}
```

Where {t} is the type of map (satellite, road, hybrid, etc) and the other attributes are specifying the coordinates and zoom level.

The possible values for {t} are as follows:

> - Default - m
> - Roads only - h
> - Roads simplified - r
> - Satellite - s
> - Satellite hybrid - y
> - Terrain - t
> - Terrain hybrid - p

That being said you do want to make sure what you're doing is NOT a violation of the terms & services.  Specifically Google WILL allow you to cache their tiles provided that you are doing so ONLY in order to improve performance and that you delete their tiles at least every 30 days, and finally you don't pull down their tiles in an attempt to make your own mapping service.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read the Google Maps Terms of Service - https://developers.google.com/maps/terms - specifically section 10.1.1